Assign partial value at compile time and partial value at runtime of same object in C++
I maintain a struct called Property which has two data members , title & value . title is string_view and value is int. Another class Foo has data members of type Property. In the below code I mentioned only two properties in Foo, but in reality it will exceed 10 . I maintain hardcoded strings for different property titles , and value data member needs to be assigned during runtime .
As I already know titles for different properties, I am thinking of creating Foo object at compile time , & assign titles of each property at compile time itself .During runtime it will only calculate value. So that it will reduce my runtime overhead .
Consider below code , this compiles and creates output what I want . but Is it correct , or is there a better way to handle this ? I am using C++20.
constexpr std::string_view one = "prop1";
constexpr std::string_view two= "prop2";

struct Property
{
    std::string_view title;
    int value;

    constexpr Property() :title{""}, value{0}{}
};

struct Foo
{
    int v1{};
    int v2{};

    Property prop1;
    Property prop2;
    constexpr Foo(int x = 0 ,  int y = 0) : v1{x}, v2{y}
    {
        prop1.title = one;
        prop2.title = two;
    }
    
    void setValue_Prop1(int a)
    {
        prop1.value = a;
    }

    void setValue_Prop2(int a)
    {
        prop2.value = a;
    }

};

int main()
{
     constexpr Foo foo{ 1,2 };

     static_assert(foo.prop1.title == "prop1");
     static_assert(foo.prop2.title == "prop2");
    
     const_cast<Foo*>(&foo)->setValue_Prop1(10); (*I cannot simply call foo.setValue_Prop1(10) as foo is constexpr)
     const_cast<Foo*>(&foo)->setValue_Prop2(20);
     
     std::cout << foo.prop1.title << " " << foo.prop1.value << std::endl;
     std::cout << foo.prop2.title << " " << foo.prop2.value << std::endl;
}


It kind of feels like what you really need is some kind of dictionary, like std::unordered_map.

template <auto Title> struct Property{/*..*/};?

const_cast<Foo*>(&foo) leads to UB as foo is const.

Feels like bad design! Why Property did not offer a constructor for partial initialization? Why class Foo is allowed to directly modify values of class Property. Why values which are bundled can't be determined in same time. And it feels that a named property should be something which is really compile time, like a template with a compile time string as parameter.

As title seems "fixed" to the property, you might template it:
constexpr char one[] = "prop1";
constexpr char two[] = "prop2";

template <auto Title> struct Property
{
    constexpr std::string_view title() const { return Title; }
    int value = 0;
};

struct Foo
{
    int v1{};
    int v2{};

    Property<one> prop1;
    Property<two> prop2;
    constexpr Foo(int x = 0,  int y = 0) : v1{x}, v2{y} {}
    
    void setValue_Prop1(int a) { prop1.value = a; }
    void setValue_Prop2(int a) { prop2.value = a; }
};

Demo

Its nice example . But when templates get expanded , it will generate more assembly code right ? If I check the assembly for this example , I see that the templates created two blocks for one & two. And this code has total assembly lines of 125 (X86 - 64 gcc 13.2 ) where as the example I provided has only 89 lines of assembly code . code . Doesn't it improve the performance at run time ?

Memory used by Foo is lesser in my version. For performance, as always, measure (But I don't think it is the bottleneck of your program anyway ;-) ).

Agree . Memory wise this code is efficient and performance wise both are performing similar . Thanks for the valuable suggestion .
